# Negative comparison with ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables:

```
sales

period_id
customer_id
product_id
value

total_sales

period_id
customer_id
product_id
value
```

I want to select every combination of `period_id` and `customer_id` that exists on `sales` but don't exists on `total_sales`. I believe there's a short way to do this. But every approach I thought involves N+1 queries.

How can I do this?

Comment: what DB engine you are using ?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: I'm concerned about unique combinations of those two attributes. Not for every repetition it can have with different product_id's or values.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is precisely the case where it's reasonable to diverge from the purist ActiveRecord approach and bring some SQL to the table. This should do the trick perfectly well:

```
Sale.find_by_sql("
   SELECT * FROM sales WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM total_sales 
                WHERE total_sales.period_id = sales.period_id AND 
                      total_sales.customer_id = sales.customer_id)
")
```

I suppose it also can be done in a more ActiveRecordish style, but it will most certainly lose clarity of the code.

Of course if you ever drop this to you codebase, you really should wrap it in a method and leave in the model, so that SQL code at least doesn't bleed into the controller.

Hope this helps!

P.S. Oh, here's the SQL fiddle I used to test this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eaf1d/1

Comment: This however still introduces N+1 problem.

Comment: I don't really see how. That's just one query. If you ever need to eager load related models, you're absolutely free to add those to the statement. I omitted them both for the sake of brevity and for general unawareness of what those models are.

Comment: Inner `SELECT 1` has to be executed for every single row in `sales` table. The fact that this is one SQL query doesn't mean it is N+1 free.

Comment: Query planner is smart enough not to do that. At least in Postgres it does just one seq scan for each table: http://pastie.org/10223053#39,43. I guess things might change should there be thousands of records and some indices and stuff, but I still don't think it will be N+1.

Comment: From my experience it is, had a similar query in sql server once, it took ages to complete. I am not sure how smart querry had to be so it do not need to do N searches in total_sales here.

Comment: Pastie shows the exact query plan from a real PostgreSQL server. Turns out it's just as smart to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

How about you first get the list that matches, then use that to get the rows that you actually want:

```
    unwanted_ids = Sale.joins('inner join total_sales on sales.period_id = total_sales.period_id and sales.customer_id = total_sales.customer_id').pluck('distinct sales.id')
    wanted_rows = unwanted_ids.any? Sale.where('id not in (?)', unwanted_ids) : Sale.all
    wanted_rows.select(:period_id, :customer_id) #if you only want these two
```

This way you only need two queries.

EDIT:

You can also do this:

```
    Sale.joins('left outer join total_sales on sales.period_id = total_sales.period_id and sales.customer_id = total_sales.customer_id').where('total_sales.period_id is null')
```

Does it in one query